# Is there a way to pair entrys by rows to give pairs such that there is maximum overlap by columns?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sorry, for the poor phrasing. I am struggling to find a good way to describe this problem, so I will go with an example. Say I have a bunch of people that I need to pair up together based on similarities between rows. If my data looked like something below, how would I go about pairing people up by the number of times a name matches in each row. For example, Name 1 and Name 4 match twice but so do Name 1 and Name 2 so returning either sets of pairs is fine as shows below.

Data:

```
|Name 1 |Name 2 |Name 4
|Name 3 |Name 4 |
|Name 2 |Name 4 |
|Name 1 |Name 2 |Name 3
|Name 1 |Name 4 |
|Name 2 |
```

Result:

```
|Name 1 |Name 2 |
|Name 3 |Name 4 |
```

or

```
|Name 1 |Name 4 |
|Name 2 |Name 3 |
```

I have tried looking at "group by" but since the names aren't perfectly aligned in each column, it didn't yield any useful results. I have also tried looking online to no avail as well. So, any input would be greatly appreciated. And do let me know if any further clarifications are required. Thank you.

As a side note: I am doing this analysis in Google Sheets using its modified query function set but the same SQL query formatting.

Comment: how many columns do you have?

Comment: The number of columns is arbitrary so I guess it just depends on the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 3 columns + everyone with everyone but only from the same row

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♥"&QUERY(
 IF(INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {A1:A&"♦"&B1:B; B1:B&"♦"&C1:C; A1:A&"♦"&C1:C}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"),,1)>INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {A1:A&"♦"&B1:B; B1:B&"♦"&C1:C; A1:A&"♦"&C1:C}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"),,2), {INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {A1:A&"♦"&B1:B; B1:B&"♦"&C1:C; A1:A&"♦"&C1:C}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"),,2), INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {A1:A&"♦"&B1:B; B1:B&"♦"&C1:C; A1:A&"♦"&C1:C}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"),,1)}, SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {A1:A&"♦"&B1:B; B1:B&"♦"&C1:C; A1:A&"♦"&C1:C}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦")), "where Col1<>Col2")),,9^9)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''"),,1), "♥"), "where Col1 <>' '"))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you, I really appreciate your help. If you have time, could you please explain how this could be expanded to more columns? From what I can understand, this is paring columns in the nC2 format and brute forcing the pairs (Please feel free to correct me if I am missing something). So all I would need to do to add a fourth column would be to pair the D column with the A, B, C columns and nothing else, right? Changing `A1:A&"♦"&B1:B; B1:B&"♦"&C1:C; A1:A&"♦"&C1:C` to `A1:A&"♦"&B1:B; B1:B&"♦"&C1:C; A1:A&"♦"&C1:C; C1:C&"♦"&D1:D; A1:A&"♦"&D1:D; B1:B&"♦"&D1:D`

Comment: @KING_VA yes for the expansion. the idea is simple... brute force pairs of columns into virtual array { } then use IF(A1>B1, B1&A1, A1&B1) logic to sort it column-wise. and then remove A1 = A1 matches and sort it by frequency

Answer (score 0):

for 3 columns + everyone with everyone no matter of rows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♥"&QUERY(
 IF(INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B1:B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(B1:B))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"),,1)>INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B1:B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(B1:B))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"),,2), {INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B1:B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(B1:B))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"),,2), INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B1:B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(B1:B))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦"),,1)}, SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B1:B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(B1:B))), CHAR(9)));
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C1:C)), CHAR(9)))&"♦"&
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))}),
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦")), "where Col1<>Col2")),,9^9)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''"),,1), "♥"))
```

[image]